# How to get the new mail notification in Android using JavaMail?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get new mail notifications using `JavaMail` (in Android app). I'm using `IdleManager` to do the job and it gives an Exception:

> Folder is not using SocketChannels

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the [IdleManager javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html)?

> Due to limitations in the Java SE nio support, a SocketChannel must be used instead of a Socket to connect to the server. However, SocketChannels don't support all the features of Sockets, such as connecting through a SOCKS proxy server. SocketChannels also don't support simultaneous read and write, which means that the idle method can't be used if SocketChannels are being used; use this IdleManager instead. To enable support for SocketChannels instead of Sockets, set the `mail.imap.usesocketchannels` property in the Session used to access the IMAP Folder. (Or `mail.imaps.usesocketchannels` if you're using the "imaps" protocol.) This will effect all connections in that Session, but you can create another Session without this property set if you need to use the features that are incompatible with SocketChannels.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Android, even when using `mail.imaps.usesocketchannels` which does cause JavaMail to use `SocketChannel.open()`,  IdleManager then tests correct use by calling `Socket.getChannel()`, which is hardcoded to return null.

```
public SocketChannel getChannel() {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, or if it does you should rephrase it because it's unclear.

Comment: Sorry, maybe this should have been a comment rather than an answer, but it does appear that even following the instructions in the JavaMail docs, IdleManager doesn't work on Android because the test it uses to check SocketChannels are in use will always return null